# Write a complete program in real-address mode that: 1) Prompts the user to read from the keyboard one uppercase letter between K and P

Tags: assembly, masm, dos, irvine16

Write a complete program in real-address mode that:

1. Prompts the user to read from the keyboard one uppercase letter between K and P.
2. Validates the input and if the character is not in the range prompt the user again and again until 
   a valid character is entered.
3. Displays the 5 neighboring letters on each side.

For example, if the user enters a letter ‘M’ then the output would be: HIJKL M NOPQR.
i try on solve it but my answer is wrong

```
include irvine16.inc

.data
M1 byte "Enter one upper case letter between K and P : $"
letter byte 1,?,1

.code
main PROC
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax

L1: mov ah,9 ;display msg m1
  lea dx,M1
  int 21h

mov ah,01h ;read a char
lea dx,letter
int 21h

mov bl,letter
CMP bl,'K'
Jb L1
CMP bl, 'P'
Ja L1


mov cx,5
lea si, letter
L3:
 dec si
loop L3

mov cx,11
lea si, letter
L2: sub si,5
  mov ah,05h
int 21h

LOOP L2



mov ah, 4ch
int 21h

main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not [how int 21h / function 01h works](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2552.htm). The character is returned in `AL`:

```
mov ah,01h ;read a char
int 21h

cmp al,'K'
```

---

This code makes no sense:

```
mov cx,5
mov  bl  
L3:
dec si 
loop L3
```

It won't assemble since `mov bl` isn't a valid istruction. Even if it did, it serves no purpose.

---

```
mov ah,05h
int 21h
```

That's not the function you want. To write a character to the standard output you should use [function 02h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm) with the character placed in `DL`.

Comment: i try to correct it but it still wrong

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that. _What_ about it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also should consider pushing valuable registers before interruption and poping them back after. I don't quite remember how all of 21h functions work, but AFAIR some might affect for example cx register resulting in unpredictable loops.